# Are C structs ABI compliant?

Tags: c++, c, struct, abi

Let's say I have a VC++ based executable and library. In order to keep the build process of both components truly independent, I can only work with plain old C types when exchanging data between both binaries.

For example, returning a `std::string` from the library to the executable is not possible, since a new MSVC runtime would require both components to be updated. Therefore, I would have to resort to a `char*` type.

However, I've wondered how structs fit into the picture. If I fill these with C types, would they still be ABI compliant? Or does the struct employ certain techniques, which would put them on par with classes, thereby rendering them as non-ABI compliant? Would it make a difference, if I'd return such a struct via a pointer versus a normal return type?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Which ABI are you talking about?  There are hundreds, if not thousands of flavors of them.

Comment: As far as I know the `C` standard doesn’t say anything about ABI, not even for C, however for C there is a de facto ABI so it will be compatible, but is not a standard guarantee. Please note that it is just my understanding of the phenomena. Wait for other answers.

Comment: "In order to keep the build process of both components truly independent, I can only work with plain old C types when exchanging data between both binaries." this statement at least questionable

Comment: @wallyk My question was referring to the missing C++ ABI

Comment: Tips for C ABI stability: Use a struct. Put the size of the struct or a version integer as the first member. Pass by pointer. So in the future with version 2 of your library it can detect receiving an old version struct when called.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Or a future version struct, for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is guaranteed that you can use c-compiled c-structs from c++ code. That is a basic to use c-libraries from c++ code at all. For example, you can use the posix api data structures, fill them from c++ code and use it with c-functions from c++ code.

If that will not work, you never could use any c-library anymore from c++. Can't believe that this scenario will become true :-)

You have to take care for name demangling with `extern "C"` and don't change manually the layout of data structures with packing options. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing with this question... if you are asking this question you are probably doing something non-portable, like using a struct/union/variable to do byte order switching or something... So once you are in this land, you basically can only expect it to work on the systems that you have unit tests written for...

as for a standard ABI, in C you will often find a single ABI for your architecture, or at least per arch / object format combo...

so for x86_86 you find one ABI for pretty much all of the POSIX world... the ABI specifies things like how to pack structs, so you can build code that runs pretty consistently on these "normal systems" but it isn't going to be "Portable" or "Standard"... but that may not really matter to you.

for C++ it is pretty much the wild west and you can't even guarantee things below the language level between different versions of the same compilers... It isn't as bad as it used to be, but you will still see problems from time to time, and that is why library vendors may still ship versions for each version of VS...